# What is the proper syntax for this SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I am trying the following SOQL query and getting an error stating the query is malformed.

```
Select Id from Program__c Where Id In
(Select ParentId from Attachment
where Description LIKE '%Resume%')
```

Comment: I don't have access to an org right now, but I will say that LIKE isn't case sensitive. Try using just one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the same query using Account rather than Program__c and got the message:

> Entity 'Attachment' is not supported for semi join inner selects.

Instead you can rework the query to get the same data.

```
Select ParentId from Attachment where Description like '%Resume%' and parent.type = 'Program__c'
```

You already have the ParentId with the ID of the Program__c record so you don't need the In clause.

---

Note that the [Understanding Relationship Query Limitations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm) documentation states:

> **You cannot filter against the content of textarea fields**, blobs, or Scontrol components in any object.

That doesn't appear to be correct with respect to the Attachment Description textarea field as the query returns the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one problem, which is that it is not possible to filter on the Description field (or any long-text field for that matter) in the WHERE clause of your SOQL.

Comment: I just tried a direct query against Attachment and was able to have a LIKE clause against the Description field. The Description field is of text area rather than a long text area.
This seems to contradict the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf) which says:  "You cannot filter against the content of **textarea** fields, blobs, or Scontrol components in any object"